# Extension: Use runtime.sendMessage/port.postMessage with only activeTab permission?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, permissions, firefox-addon

I'm reading about [message passing](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) between extension and webpage, and I have a question about permissions.

My use case is:  I need to communicate with all webpages, but only the active one. On the webpage, when the user clicks on a button "`[Connect with my Extension]`", it sends a message to the extension. What I'm doing now, is I'm injecting a content_script inside all the webpages:

```
// manifest.json snippet

  "permissions": ["storage"],
  "content_scripts": [{
    "js": ["content.js"],
    "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
    "run_at": "document_start"
  }],
```

and `content.js` does `chrome.runtime.sendMessage`/`chrome.runtime.onMessage` with the background. It works, but when I publish my extension, Chrome says:

> Because of the following issue, your extension may require an in-depth review:
>
> - Broad host permissions
>
> Instead of requesting broad host permissions, consider using the
>   activeTab permission, or specify the sites that your extension needs
>   access to. Both options are more secure than allowing full access to
>   an indeterminate number of sites, and they may help minimize review
>   times.
>
> The activeTab permission allows access to a tab in response to an
>   explicit user gesture.
>
> ```
> {   ...   "permissions": ["activeTab"] }
> ```

My question is: is there a way to achieve what I want by using `activeTab` only, as Chrome suggests?

My initial understanding is that NO. `activeTab` is only activated [on some specific user interactions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/activeTab#invoking-activeTab), whereas I would need to activate it on button click inside the webpage. So my only hope is to battle with Chrome's "in-depth reviews". Is that right?

Thanks.

Comment: Your assessment is correct. There's no way `activeTab` can help in your scenario. However it's unclear why you need that button in the page if you can provide the same when the user clicks the extension icon in the toolbar.

Comment: In my case, it's a "Login" button, I would much rather have this login button inside the webpage, UX-wise.

Comment: I find it surprising, actually. Unlike userscripts, extensions have a dedicated place to control and invoke their UI, so they don't need to cramp themselves into the volatile page UI. Also, extensions can be assigned a hotkey on chrome://extensions page (see [commands](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/commands) API).

Comment: `Also, extensions can be assigned a hotkey on chrome://extensions page.`

Can you elaborate on this? Is it related to https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/commands?

Comment: Would it be possible to add a hotkey shortcut to my extension, and programmatically "press" those keys from the webpage (e.g. using https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596481/is-it-possible-to-simulate-key-press-events-programmatically)?

Comment: 1) Eh? That's exactly what my comment says, see the documentation for more info. 2) No.

Comment: 1) I posted my comment before you edited yours and added the last parenthesis. 2) Could you elaborate why?

Comment: Those hotkeys are processed in the UI layer, not in tab contents layer.

Comment: [Trigger shortcut in a Chrome extension](//stackoverflow.com/a/37993879)